# Custom class parsing default in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When reading data from `Firebase` database and using a custom class to parse from it defaults to certain class when deserializing. Is it possible to change these defaults?

Example:

```
{
  "test_object": {
      "some_value": 1,
      "data_list": {
         "-Kgz-lc9kz4AES9oisJT": true,
         "-Ki9ud2roOHX9f8OLX4b": true,
         "-Ki9vbjJm747LERfi7tg": true
      }
}


public class TestObject {
  private int someValue;
  private HashMap<String, Boolean> dataList;

  ... getters and setters ...
}
```

This example works at it should when calling `TestObject value = dataSnapshot.getValue(TestObject.class);`

The problem here is that the `data_list` is deserialised into a `HashMap` which is not sorted. But adding entries using firebase's keys is.

I know I could just do `dataSnapshot.child("data_list").getChilren()` and read them myself and put it in any data structure I like or create another ignored getter and convert the HashMap but that feels like a workaround.
I was wondering if it's possible to just change the defaults.